Как очистить память SheetImageLoader
Пишу программку. Суть - закидываю exlec файли, она пробегает по файлу в поиске картинок и должна эти картинки сохранить, но столкнулся с проблемой которую не могу решить. Вот программа. Выкладываю максимально упрощенный вариант, до которого добрался в поисках ошибок.
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(await bot.download(document))
sheet = book.active

merged_cells = list(map(str, sheet.merged_cells.ranges))
for item in merged_cells:
    sheet.unmerge_cells(item)
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)

for i in range(1, 100):
    if image_loader.image_in(f'Z{i}'):
        print(i, image_loader.image_in(f'Z{i}'))

это кусок, который отвечает за поиск картинок. Картинки всегда на разных строках, но но всегда в столбце Z. В итоге програ первый фал обрабатывает идеально, а когда кидаю второй файл, она почему то помнит список адресов первого файла и я получаю ошибку, так как она пытается сохранить картинку из ячейки, в которой нет этого файла. Я в тупике, как только не пробовал уже, не смог придумать что делать. Ниже выгладываю полную прогу, вдруг дело не в этом куске.
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader
from aiogram import types, Router, F, Bot
from oficiant import key_officiant

router = Router()

class Doc(StatesGroup):
    first = State()

async def loading_ttk_category(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.clear()
    await state.update_data(first=message.document)
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию', reply_markup=key_officiant.get_group('load_menu'))

@router.callback_query(key_officiant.CallbackFactoryGroup.filter(F.action == 'load_menu'))
async def loading_ttk_final(call: types.CallbackQuery,
                            callback_data: key_officiant.CallbackFactoryGroup, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    data = await state.get_data()

    document = data['first']
    # name_f = data['first'].file_name
    await state.clear()
    # group = callback_data.value

    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(await bot.download(document))
    sheet = book.active

    merged_cells = list(map(str, sheet.merged_cells.ranges))
    for item in merged_cells:
        sheet.unmerge_cells(item)

    # with open(f'oficiant/{group}.json') as f:
    #     templates = json.load(f)
    #
    # templates[name_f[:-5]] = {}

    image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)

    for i in range(1, 100):
        if image_loader.image_in(f'Z{i}'):
            print(i, image_loader.image_in(f'Z{i}'))

    # t = 1
    # t_f = sheet.max_row
    # for i in range(t, t_f):
    #
    #     if image_loader.image_in(sheet.cell(row=i, column=26).coordinate):
    #         print(i, image_loader.image_in(sheet.cell(row=i, column=26).coordinate))
    #
    #         image = image_loader.get(sheet.cell(row=i, column=26).coordinate)
    #
    #         image.save(f'oficiant/img/{sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value}.jpg')
    #
    #         image.close()
    #
    #         templates[name_f[:-5]][sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value] = {}
    #
    #         y = i
    #         while sheet.cell(row=y, column=1).value != "1":
    #             y += 1
    #
    #         while sheet.cell(row=y, column=3).value is not None:
    #             templates[name_f[:-5]][sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value][
    #                 sheet.cell(row=y, column=1).value] = sheet.cell(
    #                 row=y, column=3).value.replace("ПФ_", "")
    #             y += 1
    # with open(f'oficiant/{group}.json', 'w') as f:
    #     json.dump(templates, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4 )

    book.close()
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Загружено')


Вроде нашел как побороть эту беду. Не знаю на сколько это корректно, но помогла вот такая строчка image_loader._images.clear(). Те приходится принудительно очищать словарь картинок которые были получены из предыдущего файла.
